# How to print the selected values from a checkboxGroupInput for debugging purpose in R Shiny?

Tags: r, shiny

I'm trying to create an application which final goal is to select the rows of a matrix that meets some conditions selected by the user using Shiny elements(`checkboxGroupInput, sliderInput, etc`)
For exemplification purposes, let's consider data being part of a `global.R` file:

#### global.R

```
data <- t(combn(20, 5))  # 20 has been chosen for simplicity. In reality is a variable selected from c(20, 30, 45).
```

In `ui.R` and `server.R`, I have created a set of `checkboxGroupInput` to reflect the range `c(1:20)` from which the user can select some numbers.

#### ui.R

```
....
uiOutput(outputId = "numSelector")
....
```

#### server.R

```
     ....... 
     output$numSelector <- renderUI({
        out <- checkboxGroupInput(
            inputId = "numSelector",
            label   = "Select the numbers",
            choices = selectRange(input$dataName),
            inline = TRUE
        )
        return(out)
    })
   ........
```

For debugging purposes, I would like to print out the selected values via `checkboxGroupInput` (or any other Shiny elements, in fact) and filter the rows of `data` based on these values.
Any suggestion?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using the code above, you can call a vector of the values selected using `input$numSelector`. These can be passed to a data frame for filtering, or to any other Shiny output object.

Print Values:

```
print(input$numSelector)
```

Filter

```
data[data$dataName %in% input$numSelector,]
```

To get this print code to run, it would need to be placed inside a observe() function.

Comment: I have added the following  `selectedValues <- reactive({
        print("Numbers selected via checkboxes:")
        print(input$numSelector)
      }) ` and I want to print it in R environment not in browser. Any idea?

Comment: `observe({
      print(input$numSelector)    
    })` inside your Server.R should work, edited the above to reflect

Comment: Thanks! You might want to edit your answer by adding what you put in comments for the answer to be rounded up.